# In a bash shell, is `rm -rf ./*` better/safer than `rm -rf *`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rm

In a Linux bash shell, I saw someone typing `rm -rf ./*` because he wanted to remove every file and folder of the current folder. I wonder what is the benefit of typing `./*` rather than `*` ?

I think it is better to use the simpler form `rm -rf *` because it is shorter, and using `rm -rf ./*` if you accidentally add a space between the `.` and the `/` this can cause disaster (`rm -rf . /*`).

Am I right ?

Comment: The disaster only occurs if you're logged in a root (usually not a good idea) or if you prefix the command with `sudo`. Always double-check commands under `sudo` before you hit enter. But to answer your question, there is no difference between the two commands. Note that neither command will delete dot files. Using `bash` as opposed to any other shell is not relevant, the glob expansion is the same.

Comment: @doneal24 it depends, disaster can be as severe if you are not root, once the rm hits your home or your mounted NAS.

Comment: Distaster means different things to different people. Rebuilding a system from bare metal is time consuming. Restoring a user’s home directory because of his error is less of a problem. One is a re-install followed by custom configuration changes, the other is simply restoring from backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better solution is `rm -rf ./*`. Shell globs (wildcards) are expanded before the command is executed, and there is no significant restriction on file names, which means that certain classes of filename can affect the command execution itself. Here's an example:

```
# Create a playground
mkdir fun
cd fun

# Create four files
touch x y z ./-i
ls    # Output is four files: -i  x  y  z

# Remove them per the original question
rm -rf *
```

At this point the command - and the wildcard - is expanded by the shell as follows:

```
rm -rf -i x y z
```

The result is that when `rm` runs it sees another option (`-i`), which negates the `-f` and turns it into interactive mode:

```
rm: remove regular empty file 'x'?
...
```

Note that even if you respond `y` to each of the questions about removing a file, you still won't end up with an empty directory - the file `-i` will remain.

The correct solution is either to prefix the set of files with `--` ([POSIX guideline 10](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)), which tells many commands to stop parsing the command line for arguments, or simply to use `./*` instead of `*`:

```
rm -rf -- *
rm -rf ./*
```

(To remove the file `-i`, of course you would simply `rm ./-i`.)

Oh, and in response to your "*`rm -rf . /*` can cause disaster*" - yes it can, so take care when using `rm -rf` and any form of wildcard.